# How to install SpriteKit-Spring extension

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to use the SpriteKit-Spring Extension in my Swift SpriteKit project, but I do not get it working.
The GitHub repro is [here](https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring), although there is an instruction, I do not get it working in my project.
So what I did is:

- I downloaded the file 'SpriteKit-Spring.swift'
- dragged it into my Xcode project
- added 'import SpriteKit_Spring' at the top of my GameScene.swift file.

And then I got the error from the compiler, that there is no such module 'SpriteKit_Spring'. 
What did I do wrong? I thought I followed the instructions. And I did not get the pods install right unfortunately, thats why I added this extension manually.

Comment: you don't need the import statement if you have just dragged the swift file to your project